# The white line on the tyre is not coming out of rim

Tags: tire

I wanted to change the tyre but the tyre is not inflating properly I tried with 3 different tyres what might be the problem?
Is there any chance of rim damage or alignment problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  It would be easier to get help if you provided more information.  What is the make and size of the rim?  Of the tyre?  Can you include a photo to show the problem?

Comment: Do you have a tube inside the tyre?   Is there a core inside your valve?  Is this on a bicycle or a car ?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you have tyres with a reflective strip or some other marking on the sidewall and you can see that it’s not radially symmetric, with more or less sidewall visible in some parts as you go around the rim.

This usually means that the tyre bead is not properly seated in the rim’s hooks. You can often solve it by inflating to the maximum pressure of your tyre (or even slightly above). Around 3 or 4 bar they tend to just *pop* into position. Of course release air to your desired pressure after doing this.

But first make sure the tyre is actually properly installed and the tube (if you are using one) not pinched between tyre and rim. I prefer to inflate to a very very low pressure and go around the rim, pushing the tyre away from the rim and checking that I don’t see the tube between rim and tyre. Often this is also already enough to seat it properly.

Comment: If simple inflation doesn't sort it out, repeated inflation might but it's easier to let it down, get the bead wet all over (you can use slightly soapy water but I just use plain) and then pump it up again.  Also roll/bounce it on the floor at various inflations from barely full up to  max. pressure

Comment: this is OK if you dont have a rim channel (deeper section of the rim to make tire removal easier) in this case, only put 1/4-1/3 the recommended pressure (barely past flat) and push the bead around the rim so you know it seats properly. Over inflating an improperly seated tire can cause a blow out (and Slime in your eye if you are not careful, I know from experience...)